# Branches - Some Private, Some for Pull Request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I and am just starting to learn git command line. I forked a git project, cloned it, added the original as a remote, created a branch, edited a file, committed and created a pull request. All seems well.

Now I wish to make another branch, to fix an issue that is specific to my setup. I don't want to have that end up back at the remote/original git project. So I create a branch, make the edit and commit.

But what now? What happens when the remote/original makes a change? How do I synchronise with my project and monitor if these new changes will impact my private changes? Do I merge my branch with my master, or will I always have to keep this branch separate and run this branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on continuing to contribute to the remote/original project, but would also like to develop features for your own purposes that will never be sent as a pull request and ultimately merged, then you'll either want to keep your independent work in a separate working branch indefinitely (and branch off of it for future private development), or alternatively maintain a separate code-base for your forked repo and manage it independently from the remote/original project.

I think the latter option makes the most sense, as your private development will create a functionally different project, and you'll still be able to use the remote origin on your independent code-base to pull in the latest community changes (and resolve any conflicts with your work).

To answer your question in the comments, on how to keep your feature branch in sync with the latest developments on master, you can do the following:

`git checkout master`

`git pull origin master`

This will get your master branch up to date.

`git checkout feature/branch`

`git merge --no-ff master`

This will get your feature branch up to date with master.

Comment: I think I have a 'separate repository' when I forked...? Say I make a public_branch, and do a pull request on it. At the same time, I want to make a private_branch with my special mods. How do I make my private_branch _include_ the modifications made in public_branch? Once the public_branch pull-request has been accepted, how do I make that part of my master branchm to keep my repository in synch? How do I update my private_branch with these new changes?

Comment: If you want to use the master branch, but you don't intend on making pull requests for your private feature branches, then it would make sense to have two separate code bases.  One for managing contributions to the original repository and one for managing changes to your fork.  If you don't mind keeping your private changes in branches, you could keep everything in the same code base, and just periodically pull down master and merge master into your private feature branches.

Comment: but with two code bases, I would need to synch the 'public' one and then synch to my 'private' one...?

Comment: You can always `git remote add original [url]` on your fork codebase and then `git pull original master` when you want to sync up with the latest development on the original repository.

Comment: I've updated the answer a bit to answer your master/private branch question above.

Comment: So I have my repository with private_branch. I install this with `npm git://....#private_branch`. All is well. I find a bug/feature that I'd like to add to the remote/original repo. I `pull origin master` create a `feature/branch` and submit a PR for that. I then want to include that in my private branch, so I do a `checkout private_branch` and then `merge --no-ff feature/branch` and it will merge the changes made in the new feature with my private branch? And then `git push`? `git commit`?

Comment: You can git push your private_branch if you want, but there is no need to git commit, unless you had merge conflicts that were resolved.

Comment: A GitHub fork *is* a separate repository. However, the GitHub interface is far less powerful than "real Git" so you will probably want a third repository locally, on your own computer. This third repository can have *two* other-Git-repos it talks to, which you would typically call `origin`: your own GitHub fork; and `upstream`: the original repo from which you made your fork. The confusing thing is that *every separate Git repo has its own branches*. At fetch and/or push time, you may synchronize some of your branches with some of their branches, "they" being whichever other Git you talk to.

Answer (score 0):

> make another branch, to fix an issue that is specific to my setup

--> Don't do that. Use branch what you worked on.

You must change one or few files, one or few line of code, v.v.. These change don't push to your git repository also remote git repository.

When you need update/synchronize/merge source code, ignore what you changed. (You can backup your own files then copy it back).